# why does read_html return a dataframe which can't be processed with .melt?

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting a data science exercises and I need to use the data from the following link -[link to data on github](https://github.com/tchagau/Introduction-to-Data-Science-in-Python/blob/1b70c894eeaf247707e7b5736f627f98a26e1a38/Assignment_4/assets/wikipedia_data.html). I read this data with read_html and process it then melt the data into one column, however doing this gives me the error "ValueError: Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional". I'm confused because I've tested this on a test data set and it works fine. Is there something distinct about the dataframe created by read_html? I've probed the dataframe in every way I can think of but I can't find an answer. Can someone please explain this to me?

```
cities = pd.read_html("assets/wikipedia_data.html", skiprows=1)
cities = cities[0].dropna(axis=0, thresh=4)
labels=['city',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
cities.columns = [labels]
cols=[1,2,3,4,9]
cities.drop(cities.columns[cols], axis=1, inplace=True)
cities = cities.melt(id_vars=['City'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need extract `[]` when reassigning column header

```py
labels=['City',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
cities.columns = labels
```

Comment: thankyou, that works great. What is the difference when I use the square brackets?

Comment: @ian4339 When you use another brackets wrapper, pandas intents to treat it as multiindex.